# SPF not working with django, back arrow not changing page

Tags: javascript, html, django, spf

I'm using spfjs, refer to this link - http://youtube.github.io/spfjs/ but when I click the back arrow after clicking on the link with the `.spf-link` class and going to that page, it doesn't change the page, it only updates the title.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spf/2.4.0/spf.js"></script>
<script>
  spf.init();
</script>

<li class="is-inline"><a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="spf-link">Sign Up</a></li>
```

Comment: Local hosting (127.0.0.1) or live?

Comment: It's localhost, does it have to be live?

Comment: Might have to be live for auth reasons. Try it live see what happens